# How to perform a text/phrase search with spring-data and elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have an Index with documents with multiple text fields.
I want to perform a search that should match documents that

- either start with that *exact* text,
- either contain that *exact* text,
- or end with that *exact* text

on a few pre-defined fields, and another *static* condition.

In the first place I thought about implementing a search with the use of queryStringQuery and wildcards

```java
var queryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();
queryBuilder
    .must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(String.format("*%s*", QueryParser.escape(filterText)))
         .field(FIELD_1)
         .field(FIELD_2)
         .field(FIELD_3)
         .analyzeWildcard(true))
    .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery(FIELD_X, "...")));
var nativeQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(queryBuilder).withPageable(pageable).build();
elasticsearchOperations.search(nativeReq, MyEntity.class);
```

This solution worked fine as long as the filterText is one word, but once the default/standard analyzer tokenises the text I get unexpected results (for my use-case).

I've been thinking about searching with phrase queries as such:

```java
var queryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();
var insideQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder();
insideQuery
    .should(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery(FIELD_1, filterText))
    .should(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery(FIELD_2, filterText))
    .should(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery(FIELD_3, filterText));
queryBuilder
    .should(insideQuery).minimShouldMatch(1)
    .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery(FIELD_X, "...")));
```

But I still get unexpected results.

I also tried a solution similar with the first one and tried to force es to use the [keyword analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html) but I did not manage to do so (0 results), maybe because my mappings define that fields as text not keywords?!

Can you please help me/point me to a solution that will match my exact use-case?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the field types from `Text` to `Keyword` and adjusting the code as follows:

```java
var queryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();

// match exact phrase using keyword analyzer
queryBuilder
    .should(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery(FIELD_1, filterText).analyzer("keyword"))
    .should(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery(FIELD_2, filterText).analyzer("keyword"))
    .should(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery(FIELD_3, filterText).analyzer("keyword"));

// match beginning/end/middle of text with wildcard
var wildcardFilter = String.format("*%s*", filterText);
queryBuilder.
    .should(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery(FIELD_1, wildcardFilter))
    .should(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery(FIELD_2, wildcardFilter))
    .should(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery(FIELD_3, wildcardFilter));

// at least one optional clause ("should") has to match 
queryBuilder.minimumShouldMatch(1);
queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery(FIELD_X, "...")));
```

seems to work pretty well for most of the cases I tested against.

Probably it's not the best way to achieve this, but it gets the job done.